# Unit test class with stubs. Should I configure stubs to return ALWAYS correct values?

Tags: unit-testing, stubs

this is one of my questions about unit testing.

I'm reading The Art Of Unit Testing and at chapter 3 the author shows how to remove dependency between one or more classes. That seems clear to me. What's not absolutely clear is the following point.

When I configure a test method with a stub, I configure it to return a specific value. Then I call the tested method exposed by the tested class. This method executes some logic and uses the return value of the stub. The problem is: if the stub is configured to return the wrong value my test will probably fail.

So the question is: when I use stubs, should I ALWAYS configure them to return the expected value? In my opininon this should be the correct way to test as if the stub return always the expected value I'm sure to test only the logic inside the tested method.

What do you think about this? Is there some case in which has some kind of sense to oblige the stub to return uncorrect values?

Thanks a lot,
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing how the sut (system under test) works under several conditions:

- the good path = configuring stubs to return *good* values and test that the sut behaves accordingly
- the sad path(s) = configure stubs with *wrong* values and verify that the sut can *handle* such cases (e.g. you can test that it throws an Exception using the ExpectedException attribute if you're using nUnit)

Comment: Oh, that's the answer I'd have loved to receive! Thanks so much!

Comment: I've another question: Suppose I've a stub that returns True if a file has a 'ext' extension, false otherwise. My method under test calls that method with a valid extention but the stub is configured to return false (ie we are testing a sad path). What should I do to improve my method and let the test pass? The only solution I see is not to trust the stub, but... Is this correct?

Comment: The class that returns true/false depending on the extension (let's call it ExtensionValidator) is another system component. This logic will be tested elsewhere (in ExtensionValidatorTests). In our current context we are testing the sut, and for now ExtensionValidator is just a stub that will return whatever value we tell it to return. So, the true/false depending on extension logic needs not to be tested in our current context. Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Yes that answer my question but in the book there is an example that, in my opinion, is not so simple to understand. By the way that book rocks! Thanks a lot, w0lf!

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the stub method to return value depending on the test setup in some scenarios. In others to return default value, which should be valid.